# How to use multi value(array) property in OSGi?

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

I have the following service:

```
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        metatype = true)
@Service
@Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value = {ReplicationAction.EVENT_TOPIC})
public class MyService implements EventHandler {

    @Property
    private static final String MULTI_PROPERTY = "config.multiproperty";

    ........
    //another implementation
    ........
}
```

I want `MULTI_PROPERTY` to be as array value, to have possibility to use a set of values like on image:

[image]

How to implement it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `unbounded` attribute to specify multivalued property and use the `cardinality` attribute to restrict the number of entries.

```
 @Property(unbounded = PropertyUnbounded.ARRAY, cardinality=10, label = "Some Label")
 private static final String MULTI_PROPERTY = "config.multiproperty";
```

In order to read the property array you can use `#toStringArray()` method of the `PropertiesUtil`

```
PropertiesUtil.toStringArray(properties.get(MULTI_PROPERTY));
```